# Preserve Idle State after a scene transition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Animator panel]I've been making this game recently for a school project and i have a question. It has an undertale-like system and ive been wondering how to make it so the direction the player is looking at does not change after a scene transition. AKA i want to preserve the idle state. I am using blend trees for my animation. Thanks.
Edit: My Code thus far

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
public float MoveSpeed = 5f;
public Rigidbody2D PlayerBody;
public Animator PlayerAnimator;

private Vector2 Movement;
void Awake() {
DontDestroyOnLoad(PlayerAnimator.gameObject);
}
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    Movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    if (Movement != Vector2.zero)
    {
        PlayerAnimator.SetFloat("Horizontal", Movement.x);
        PlayerAnimator.SetFloat("Vertical", Movement.y);
    }
    PlayerAnimator.SetFloat("Speed", Movement.sqrMagnitude);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    PlayerBody.MovePosition(PlayerBody.position + Movement * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}

}
```

I've been trying to call DontDestroyOnLoad() on the animator object of the player in an attempt but it does not work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have any example code of what you've tried thus far? It would really help the community in answering you and teaching you at the same time if you provided your attempts to solve this problem.

Comment: @whathm Alright, I added it mate. Sorry about that

Comment: If you need to keep the status of something between scenes, you need to pass it to a class that does not get destroyed when the scene changes. See: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html I would pass the state on the Ondestroy() of your PlayerMovement class when the object is destroys in the scene unload to your immortal class, and retrieve from it the animation state on the Start() o Awake() when the secene loads